# android what is missing to show my pop up

Tags: android, popup, android-fragments

I have an app with fragments working ok,

now I need to implement some pop up views,

Im following this tutorial [Example of using PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

all seems fine, but The pop up is not showing yet, as I have a doubt on how to show the "popupWindow"

my `.java`:

```
public class Tab2HeadH1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

   //testeo popero

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2_head_buttons, container,false);

       //Buttons

       Button buttonNose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_pop_nose);

       buttonNose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                //aqui tus tareas,,

                //LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  //old errors
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                      popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

             }

      });

      Button buttonEye = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_pop_eye);

      buttonEye.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
           // onLoginClicked(v);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ss9 eye",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
      });

      return view;
   }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       ((TabActivity)getActivity()).setHeader("TAPING APPLICATION");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {

       }
    }


}
```

So what is missing to show my pop up?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you setup the Popup fine, you aren't actually calling any method to show it anywhere. Call whichever one of the following methods suits your needs to open it:

1. [showAtLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
2. [showAsDropDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown%28android.view.View%29)
3. [showAsDropDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29) (Different from #2)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate Custom pop up window you can do this use AlertDialog.Builder

```
private AlertDialog.Builder scheduleBuilder;
private AlertDialog dialog_Creater;

LayoutInflater myLayoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View v = myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_creator, null); //Replace your layout R.layout.youLayout
            scheduleBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());


            scheduleBuilder.setTitle("Edit your Schedule Memo");
            scheduleBuilder.setView(v); //set view 



            dialog_Creater = scheduleBuilder.create();
            dialog_Creater.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
PopupWindow pw;

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popnumber,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lytpopuppoppop));

// your popup layout  and  id of root layout 

pw = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
// your main layout where you display popup
pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.lytboard), Gravity.CENTER,
                        0, 0);
```